# Javascript Array indexOutOfRange when looped through in C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays

**EDIT 2**
**I accidently communicated that the exception was of type IndexOutOfBounds but it is actually of type IndexOutOfRange.**

I'm trying to save some objects to a server. These are the actions that are taken:

1. The javascript array is an array of Text objects.
2. These Text objects are put inside a TextModel list when they are transfered to the controller. (by using JQuery.Post)
3. Each element in the TextModels list then needs to be put into a new server object, TextInfo.
4. Each TextInfo object is put into a new array that's stored in a PageInfo object
5. The PageInfo object is send to the server for further processing.

The process errors on #3. For some reason I get an IndexOutOfRange exception when looping through the TextModel list. After all TextModel list elements are added (looped through) to the new TextInfo list, the error comes. This when it tries to increase the for-loops counter (i). I expect it to increase i and then exit the loop when the condition isn't met but it seemingly errors on i++.

I have no idea what could be causing this error. As seen in the code I only use the listed objects to fill the properties of the new object, I don't try to edit the properties while in the loop. Any insight as to what could cause the problem would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

*Apparently this wasn't clear enough. All objects send with the post are received as expected in the controller. Count always holds the expected amount of elements and all elements are properly set. See JSON example & Image 1 for details.*

**Text object as defined in Javascript (#1)**

```
function Text() {
    //this.Id = 0;
    this.text = "Hallo";
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.fillColor = "black";
    this.fontFamily = "Arial";
    this.fontStyle = "normal";
    this.fontSize = "18pt";
    this.fontWeight = "normal";
    this.textAlignment = "start";
    this.angle = 0;
}
function addText(text, fillColor, fontSize, fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, textAlignment, x, y, angle) {
    var textTemp = new Text;
    textTemp.text = multilineText(text, fontSize, fontFamily, fontStyle);

    textTemp.fillColor = fillColor;
    textTemp.fontSize = fontSize;
    textTemp.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    textTemp.fontWeight = fontWeight;
    textTemp.fontStyle = fontStyle;
    textTemp.x = x;
    textTemp.y = y;
    textTemp.textAlignment = textAlignment;
    textTemp.angle = angle;

    textObjects.push(textTemp);
}
```

**Javascript JQuery.Post & TextModel in Controller (#2)**

```
// Saves page information 
// Called on Save, Next / Previous Page.
// @param curPageNum The currently selected page's number.
function savePage(curPageNum) {
    var pageNumber = curPageNum;

    var json = JSON.stringify({ TextObjects: textObjects, ImageSource: imageSource, CurrentPageNumber: pageNumber });
    alert(json);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/NextprintPhotobook/SavePageInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
            showSuccess(data.message);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            showError("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het opslaan van de foto.");
        }

    });
}
```

**Controller (#3, #4)**

```
public ActionResult SavePageInfo(List<TextModel> TextObjects, string ImageSource, int CurrentPageNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                #region Define & initialize textInfoArray (Array of Textinfo objects)
                // textInfoArray used to set property of the page info object.
                TextInfo[] textInfoArray = null;
                List<TextInfo> textInfoList = new List<TextInfo>();
                if (TextObjects != null)
                {
                    // Build textInfo list.
                    // textInfoList used to build a list from the TextObjects parameter.
                    for (int i = 0; i < TextObjects.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextModel textObject = TextObjects[i];
                        PositionInfo positionInfo = null;
                        if (textObject.x >= 0 && textObject.y >= 0)
                        {
                            int xTemp = textObject.x;
                            int yTemp = textObject.y;
                            positionInfo = new PositionInfo()
                            {
                                X = xTemp,
                                Y = yTemp
                            };
                        }
                        string textTemp = textObject.text;
                        string fontFamilyTemp = textObject.fontFamily;
                        string fontSizeTemp = textObject.fontSize;
                        string fontWeightTemp = textObject.fontWeight;
                        string fontStyleTemp = textObject.fontStyle;
                        string fillColorTemp = textObject.fillColor;
                        int rotationTemp = textObject.angle;
                        string alignmentTemp = textObject.textAlignment;
                        TextInfo textInfo = new TextInfo()
                        {
                            Value = textTemp,
                            Font = fontFamilyTemp,
                            Size = fontSizeTemp,
                            Weight = fontWeightTemp,
                            Style = fontStyleTemp,
                            Color = fillColorTemp,
                            Rotation = rotationTemp,
                            Position = positionInfo,
                            Alignment = alignmentTemp
                        };
                        textInfoList.Add(textInfo);
                    }
                    textInfoArray = textInfoList.ToArray();
                }

                #endregion

                #region Define & initialize PageInfo
                PageInfo pageInfo = null;
                if (textInfoList == null)
                {
                    return Json(new APIResponse { OK = 0, message = "Er is een onbekende fout opgetreden binnen de API." }, "text/html");
                }

                string fileName = "";
                string tempSource = ImageSource;
                fileName = this.getFileNameFromSource(tempSource);

                if (fileName == null)
                {
                    return Json(new APIResponse { OK = 0, message = "Er is een onbekende fout opgetreden binnen de API." }, "text/html");
                }
                if (CurrentPageNumber <= 0)
                {
                    return Json(new APIResponse { OK = 0, message = "Er is een onbekende fout opgetreden binnen de API." }, "text/html");
                }
                pageInfo = new PageInfo()
                {
                    PageNumber = CurrentPageNumber,
                    FileName = fileName,
                    Text = textInfoArray
                };
                #endregion

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SERVER_URI);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<PageInfo>("api/Xml/SavePageInfo?hash=" + SecurityHash + "&collectionId="
                    + CollectionId + "&version=" + Version, pageInfo).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    APIResponse apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<APIResponse>().Result;

                    Logger.log("API response received, see API log for more details.");

                    return Json(apiResponse, "text/html");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log("An exception occurred while saving page info: {0}", e.Message);
            return Json(new APIResponse { OK = 0, message = "Er is een onbekende fout opgetreden bij het communiceren met de API." }, "text/html");
        }
    }
```

**JSON Example**
This is the JSON that's send:

> [{"TextObjects":[{"text":"Test
>   ","x":50,"y":50,"fillColor":"#77DD44","fontFamily":"arial","fontStyle":"normal","fontSize":"18pt","fontWeight":"normal","textAlignment":"start","angle":0}],"ImageSource":"http://localhost:22223//Cyber/1718/1/img/resized/1.jpg","CurrentPageNumber":1}]

[C# received object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdro1.png)

Comment: your first mistake is possibly setting `data: json` where json is a json string, as you are setting dataType to json already, there's no need to JSON.stringify the object before sending it in the post request

Comment: @JaromandaX I made the changes, good eye and thanks for the help. But it doesn't change anything to the main issue at hand.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the start of the controller method - what does your TextObjects list look like - is the count correct, and do the objects look valid? Can you step through the execution of the condition where it is failing?

Comment: @JohnMorgan I added the JSON that's send and a picture that displays the look of the object in C#. As you can see the count is correct. The problem is as explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: Ok, so step through the code of the for loop as it's executing. What happens just before it throws the exception? Look at the Locals window in Visual Studio as you step through.

Comment: @JohnMorgan Everything is filled in as expected. Each loop adds the expected object to the new list. But when the last element is added and the debugger returns to the loop to increase `int i` it jumps to the catch with the exception IndexOutOfRange. It won't even check the condition, it seemingly crashes on `i++`. All locals are filled as expected.

Comment: I've reproduced your code as closely as I can but I just don't get the error. I can only suggest you strip away the code in your controller bit by bit to see when the problem disappears - or try and create a .NET fiddle that reprooduces the problem

Comment: The problem was with a different method. Strange though that the debugger didn't first let me check the condition when stepping into the for loop after `i++`. Thanks for the support/help @JohnMorgan

Comment: No worries, glad it's sorted